# How to generate json from two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, node.js, json

Tell me who knows how to make a json response of the desired format from two sql requests.
Base (client groups) #1 clients_groups has id_clients and name columns.
id_clients here are client IDs through whom from the clients database.
name is the name of the section.
Base (List of clients) No. 2 clients has data about users.
How to make json. Example as needed:
`

```
{
        id: '',
        text: 'Department №1',
        children: [ // Here at the bottom you need to get a list of users by ID from department No. 1
            { id: 'User ID', text: 'Username' },
            { id: 'User ID', text: 'Username' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Department №2',
        children: [ // Here at the bottom you need to get a list of users by ID from department No. 2
            { id: 'User ID', text: 'Username' },
            { id: 'User ID', text: 'Username' }
        ]
    }
```

`

I tried to link data from an attachment through a loop. Nothing helped.

```
query("SELECT id, id_clients, name FROM clients_groups", (error, results) => {
  console.log(results);
})

[
  RowDataPacket { id: 1, id_clients: '2', name: 'Manager' },   
  RowDataPacket { id: 2, id_clients: '2, 3', name: 'Support' }
]
```

Comment: I don't see anything about clients here.  You need to show us what data you HAVE that should produce this result.

Comment: I will receive all data by ID. I just need to provide information and that's it.
{ id: 'UserID', text: 'Username' }
We get this data when, when requesting a group, we get a list of user IDs in the id_clients column.

Comment: Without seeing your input data, we can't possibly help you produce your desired output.  We don't know how all these things are related.  Where does department number come in?

Comment: This is the group table.
https://i2.paste.pics/e472c3be3487a8cc2f6a6cb787ab94c2.png
This is the user table
https://i2.paste.pics/76f533ac74e803d88f1c9f5ca1952951.png

Comment: Where does the "text" come from?  There are no department names here.  How do you decide which records to put into departments?  Do you see the problem?  You have told us NOTHING about how those records are supposed to be converted into the JSON you showed.